# Making Scrollbar angular js and framework 7 mobile

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frameworks, html-framework-7

I want to make a scrollbar to my mobile project, i am using angular js and framework 7. I want to use different devices and not fixed height. I tried nicescroll ,but it collapsed with the framework 7. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used webkit-scrollbar and it worked with fw7. It is working with all mobile devices.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    }

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```